# Record using AVAudioRecorder when mic is not available

Tags: ios

I am using AVAudioRecorder to record audio sessions.

when touch and hold on a button:
    `[self.audioRecorder record];`

When release button:
   `[self.audioRecorder stop];`

Then I check if `duration > 0`, send the message. Otherwise do nothing.

It works well on my simulator and on device. However, when running on a simulator on a remote mac mini (which doesn't have a built-in mic), it doesn't send out the message no matter how long I hold.

It's kind of impractical for me to debug on that mac mini. I wonder if anyone knows what AVAudioRecorder will record when no mic is available?